# Position matrix for a bug travelling

Tags: linear-algebra, trigonometry, complex-numbers

> A bug starts at the origin at $t=0$ and travels outward in a spiral, so that at time $t$ seconds the bug is at location $\langle x,y\rangle=\langle R^t\cos\omega t,R^t\sin\omega t\rangle$, or in polar coordinates $\langle r,\theta\rangle=\langle R^t,\omega t\rangle$.
>
> If we write the bug's location as a column vector $\displaystyle\left[\begin{matrix}x(t)\\y(t)\end{matrix}\right]$, write the matrix $R$ so that $R\displaystyle\left[\begin{matrix}x(t)\\y(t)\end{matrix}\right]$ is the bug's location $t$ seconds later.

I set it up this way:
$$
  \left[\begin{matrix}
    \displaystyle\frac{e^{it}}{2} & \displaystyle\frac{e^{-it}}{2y} \\
    \displaystyle\frac{e^{it}}{2ix} & \displaystyle\frac{e^{-it}}{2i}
  \end{matrix}\right]
  \left[\begin{matrix}
     x(t) \\
     y(t)
  \end{matrix}\right]
  =
  \left[\begin{matrix}
    R^{t}\cos(t) \\
    R^{t}\sin(t)
  \end{matrix}\right],
$$
but this doesn't seem correct to me.  What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Please do not use pictures for critical portions of your post. Pictures may not be legible, cannot be searched and are not view-able to some, such as those who use screen readers.

Comment: For some basic information about writing math at this site see e.g. [basic help on mathjax notation](/help/notation), [mathjax tutorial and quick reference](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020), [main meta site math tutorial](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559) and [equation editing how-to](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1773).

Comment: thank you, i apologize. im new here.

Comment: @georgebob I have rewritten your post with MathJax markup, please double check if I made any mistakes.  To see the markup, click on the gray [edit](https://math.stackexchange.com/posts/2568562/edit) hyperlink below the tags under your question.  Please learn MathJax, for the sake of this site.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your formulation is incorrect because $|e^{it}|=1$ for all $t\in \Bbb{R}$, so the distance from the origin is not increasing at the rate of $R^t$ times some constant.

Note that $(x(t),y(t))=(R^t\cos\omega t,R^t\sin\omega t)=R^t(\cos\omega t,\sin\omega t)$ means a dilation (since it's written "outward" in the question, $R>1$) of $R^t$ at time $t$ and a rotation of frequency $\omega/2\pi$.  It's easier to think of them one by one.

To rescale $(x,y)\mapsto(ax,by)$
$$\begin{pmatrix}a & 0 \\ 0 & b\end{pmatrix}\begin{pmatrix}x \\ y\end{pmatrix}=\begin{pmatrix}ax \\ by\end{pmatrix}$$
In this case, $a=b=R^t$.

To rotate a vector, left multiply it by the [rotation matrix $\begin{pmatrix}\cos \theta &-\sin \theta \\\sin \theta &\cos \theta \\\end{pmatrix}$](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rotation_matrix).

Hence, the desired matrix is
$$\begin{pmatrix}R^t & 0 \\ 0 & R^t\end{pmatrix}
\begin{pmatrix}\cos \theta &-\sin \theta \\\sin \theta &\cos \theta\end{pmatrix}
=\begin{pmatrix}R^t\cos \theta &-R^t\sin \theta \\ R^t\sin \theta & R^t\cos \theta\end{pmatrix}.$$

Answer (score 0):

At time t we have

$$
  \left[\begin{matrix}
     x(t) \\
     y(t)
  \end{matrix}\right]
  =
  \left[\begin{matrix}
    R^{t}\cos\omega t\\
    R^{t}\sin\omega t
  \end{matrix}\right]$$

After time t we have

$$\left[\begin{matrix}
     x(2t) \\
     y(2t)
  \end{matrix}\right]
  =
  \left[\begin{matrix}
    R^{2t}\cos2\omega t \\
    R^{2t}\sin2\omega t
  \end{matrix}\right]=
  R^{2t}\left[\begin{matrix}
    \cos^2\omega t - \sin^2\omega t\\
   2\sin\omega t \cos\omega t
  \end{matrix}\right]= 
\begin{bmatrix}R^{t}\cos \theta &-R^{t}\sin \theta \\ R^{t}\sin \theta & R^{t}\cos \theta\end{bmatrix}\left[\begin{matrix}
    R^{t}\cos\omega t\\
    R^{t}\sin\omega t
  \end{matrix}\right]$$

> Thus
>
> $$\mathcal{R}=\begin{bmatrix}R^{t}\cos \theta &-R^{t}\sin \theta \\ R^{t}\sin \theta & R^{t}\cos \theta\end{bmatrix}$$